# Programmatically generated TextViews print on each other

Tags: android, textview

I'm generating TextViews in a loop and add them to a Relative layout like this :

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_root);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  TextView textvw = new TextView(this);
  textvw.setText(Integer.toString(i));
  relativeLayout2.addView(textvw);
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
    TextView textvw2 = new TextView(this);
    textvw2 .setText(Integer.toString(j+5));
    relativeLayout2.addView(textvw2);
  }
}
```

When I do this, all textViews print on the same place. I want them to appear below each other. I mean first one will be on the top, secone one below the top and like that. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Try using a vertical Linearlayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: @TdSoft it worked, thanks.

Comment: The _reason_ they are printing on each other is because RelativeLayout, like FrameLayout, will by default draw Views in the top left corner of its bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linear layout instead of Relative layout and set the orientation to vertical if you want it one below the other.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_root);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { TextView textvw = new TextView(this);
textvw.setText(Integer.toString(i));
relativeLayout2.addView(textvw); for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { TextView textvw2 = new TextView(this);
textvw2 .setText(Integer.toString(j+5));
linearLayout2.addView(textvw2); } }
```